# DAX Query - EARLIER() - Compare with previous Quarter

Tags: powerpivot, dax, ssas-tabular

I tried to do a comparison in DAX between multiple Quarter.

In our case we use Power Pivot with a flat table as source. (No star schema)

Here is a small example:

Our source looks like this:

[image: Data source]

That's what we have now:

[image: Current PivotTable]

Here is our expected result:

[image: Expected Result]

I tried to do something with EARLIER() and EARLIEST() function, but it is definitively not good. (Like an MDX LAG() function).
In our specific case, we don't have a clear date and I'm not sure if I can use a ParallelPeriod function

```js
SumValuePrevious:=CALCULATE
(
  SUM(Data[Value]);
  FILTER(ALL(Data[Quarter]);
  SUMX
   (
           FILTER(Data; EARLIEST(Data[Quarter]) = Data[Quarter] )
           ; 
           [Value]
   )
)
)
```

But I get the same result:

[image: New Result]

Do you have something to help me?
Thank you very much for your help,
Arnaud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to work with dates is to add a date table. 
then you can use the default date functions

```
Previous Quarter:= CALCULATE(SUM(myTable[myColumn]), PREVIOUSQUARTER('Date'[Date]))
```

Adding a date table:

```
Date =
ADDCOLUMNS (
CALENDAR (DATE(2000;1;1); DATE(2025;12;31));
"DateAsInteger"; FORMAT ( [Date]; "YYYYMMDD" );
"Year"; YEAR ( [Date] );
"Monthnumber"; FORMAT ( [Date]; "MM" );
"YearMonthnumber"; FORMAT ( [Date]; "YYYY/MM" );
"YearMonthShort"; FORMAT ( [Date]; "YYYY/mmm" );
"MonthNameShort"; FORMAT ( [Date]; "mmm" );
"MonthNameLong"; FORMAT ( [Date]; "mmmm" );
"DayOfWeekNumber"; WEEKDAY ( [Date] );
"DayOfWeek"; FORMAT ( [Date]; "dddd" );
"DayOfWeekShort"; FORMAT ( [Date]; "ddd" );
"Quarter"; "Q" & FORMAT ( [Date]; "Q" );
"YearQuarter"; FORMAT ( [Date]; "YYYY" ) & "/Q" & FORMAT ( [Date]; "Q" )
)
```

Mark your date table as date table
Replace your column Quarter in your source, with the first date of the quarter. 
Create a relationship between both tables.